# Why does the same for loop runs faster in the second time?

Tags: c++, performance, for-loop, d

Initially I was comparing performance of built-in D arrays and plain pointers, but I've ended up with a different issue. For some reason if I run two identical for loops one after another, the second one always completes faster.

Here is the code:

```
import std.stdio : writeln;
import std.datetime : StopWatch;
import core.stdc.stdlib : malloc, free;

void main()
{
    immutable N = 1_000_000_000;
    StopWatch sw;

    uint* ptr = cast(uint*)malloc(uint.sizeof * N);

    sw.start();
    for (uint i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        ptr[i] = 1;
    sw.stop();
    writeln("the first for loop time: ", sw.peek().msecs(), " msecs");
    sw.reset();

    sw.start();
    for (uint i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        ptr[i] = 2;
    sw.stop();
    writeln("the second for loop time: ", sw.peek().msecs(), " msecs");
    sw.reset();

    free(ptr);
}
```

After compiling and running it with `dmd -release -O -noboundscheck -inline test.d -of=test && ./test` it prints:

```
the first for loop time: 1253 msecs
the second for loop time: 357 msecs
```

I was not sure whether this is something related to D or dmd so I've rewritten this code in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    const unsigned int N = 1000000000;

    unsigned int* ptr = (unsigned int*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned int) * N);

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (uint i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        ptr[i] = 1;
    auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto milliseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(finish-start);
    std::cout << "the first for loop time: " << milliseconds.count() << " msecs" << std::endl;

    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (uint i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        ptr[i] = 2;
    finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    milliseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(finish-start);
    std::cout << "the second for loop time: " << milliseconds.count() << " msecs" << std::endl;

    free(ptr);
}
```

and `g++ -O3 test.cpp -o test && ./test` gives similar output:

```
the first for loop time: 1029 msecs
the second for loop time: 349 msecs
```

The result is the same every time I run this code. Allocated data is too big to be cached. There is no branching points so no branching prediction issues should be involved. The memory is accessed at the same direct order at both loops so I guess this should not be related to the memory layout.

So why does the second one runs faster than the first one?

Comment: "Allocated data is too big to be cached." Are you sure? There are multiple types of caching.

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure if the D and C++ tags fit well. Probably this issue is language-agnostic?

Comment: As a guess, I suspect that the large block of memory is not actually paged in when first allocated, but becomes paged in as you walk the memory in the first loop.  The second loop doesn't page in the memory, since the memory is already "hot".

Comment: @wally I'm not sure, but 1000000000 unsigned ints is about 3.72 GiB, that is impressive cache size, at least for my PC.

Comment: Maybe the allocated memory is being processed during the first loop and procession is "memorized" in the second? Measure the exact same procedure for two arrays - allocate, loop and delete for both. If it is the same, probably this is the reason.

Comment: Use a profiler, check the machine code, etc. Everything we can do is speculate and that's beyond the site scope.

Comment: What happens if you insert a 3rd loop? What timing do you get? Try to keep the loop exactly the same (assigning both times the same value).

Comment: assembly code is identical in both cases, third run gives the same time as the second one, so that's because of paging.

Comment: You can use `ptr = new unsigned int[N]();` instead of `malloc` to zero-initialize the array. Do then both loops take the same time?

Comment: BTW your loops have no effect. I wouldn't wonder if a compiler optimized them completely away. In such measurements, it's better to use the array afterwards, such as print out the sum of its elements, to prevent such optimizations.

Comment: A third loop executes almost as fast as the second one. Different values are intentional to prevent compilers from removing identical code. Not the best way, probably, but printing summs of the arrays changes nothing, same time.

I guess the suggestion about allocating/paging at the first loop must be correct. Didn't thought of that. I'll try to check it later.

Comment: If the code for the loop can fit into the processor's instruction cache, the 2nd and more iterations will run faster because the processor doesn't need to reload the instructions from memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `uint* ptr = cast(uint*)malloc(uint.sizeof * N);` does not allocate memory until you do for loop over many elements. You can test it:

```
import core.stdc.stdlib : malloc, free;

void main()
{
    immutable N = 1_000_000_000;
    uint* ptr = cast(uint*)malloc(uint.sizeof * N);

    foreach (_; 0 .. 100)
    for (uint i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        ptr[N-1] = 1;

    // until this point almost no memory is allocated
    for (uint i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        ptr[i] = 2;

    free(ptr);
}
```

**Update**
@Eljay allready explain this in comments